# Есть ли способ анонимно "пропихнуть" *this в указатель на функцию в структуре (создать метод)

Tags: c, классы, ассемблер, x86-64

Ситуация такая: я создаю некоторое подобие классовой механики в С, но столкнулся с такой проблемой, как создание методов. Т.к в С недопустимо вложение функций в структуру, а я не хочу, чтобы методом пользовался кто-то другой, то я описываю функции отдельно в **.с** файле, а в структуру вкладываю лишь указатель на функцию, который при создании элемента класса подвязывает функции в конструкторе (late binding):

*Bitstack.h*

```
struct Stack
{
    const void* class;                          // class description goes here

    unsigned long long data[50];                // storage for stack values || messing not recommended
    unsigned int head;                          // pointer to the last element of big stack
    unsigned char bitctr;                       // pointer to the last element of bits

    // Pushes bits into the stack and automatically pushes complete 32/64 bits to the big one
    // self - pointer to the current class pointer (this)
    // value - value to push from 0 to 255
    // length - length in bits to push < 9
    void(*bPush)(void* self, unsigned char value, unsigned char length);
    // Pops bits from the stack and automatically pops complete 32/64 bits from the big one
    // self - pointer to the current class pointer (this)
    // length - length in bits to pop < 9
    short (*bPop)(void* self, unsigned char length);
};
```

*Bitstack.c*

```
void* stack_ctor(void* self, va_list *ap)
{
    struct Stack* this = self;

    this->bitctr = 0;
    this->bPop = bPop;
    this->bPush = bPush;
    this->head = 0;

    return this;
}
```

Однако здесь указатель **this** передается при помощи **void*** self - как первый элемент функции. На ассемблере, при вызове указателя на функцию, выглядит это все так:

S1->bPush(S1, 1, 2); // S1 является результатом функции new(), которая работает почти также как и в C++

```
 mov         r8b,2                 ; 2 записывается в регистр r8
 mov         dl,1                  ; 1 записывается в регистр rdx
 mov         rcx,qword ptr [S1]    ; указатель на себя
 mov         rax,qword ptr [S1]    ; !Почему я не могу использовать его??
 call        qword ptr [rax+1A0h]  ; вызов указателя на функцию
```

По сути на уровне ассемблера я теряю инструкцию копированием указателя на *S1*. Есть ли способ написать код так, чтобы из *rax* указатель попадал в аргументы функции или в саму функцию, делая из нее метод?

***Доп информация***:
*сорс код*: https://github.com/Agrael1/Veritas-3D/tree/master/ConsoleApplication5

*Kомпилятор*: MSVC 2015 (Visual Studio 2015), также компилировал на GCC на другой машине. Режим х64 (это важно, поскольку он не поддерживает inline assembler)

*Язык*: ANSI-C

Был у меня вариант написать свою конвенцию вызова, но __declspec(naked) не работает, пишет:
Ошибка  C2485   naked: неизвестный расширенный атрибут

Comment: Собственно, вот потому Страуструп и начал работу над "С с классами"...

Comment: Мне это кажется очень, очень плохой идеей. Вы увеличиваете размер структуры (за счет указателей на функции) просто так, чтобы иметь синтаксис "вызова методов как в С++". Лучше используйте функции напрямую, без указателей, и передавайте в них структуру одним из параметров. Не так красиво, зато лишняя память не расходуется и нет потенциальной потери в скорости из-за использования указателей на функции.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat это не поможет с виртуализацией, только создаст кучу коллизий, ибо в проекте есть методы, которые переопределяются при наследовании. Да и просто найти функцию (например отрисовки полигона) в проекте граф библиотеки будет сложной задачей.

Comment: А память не жалко в каждой структуре таскать указатели на все функции ? В C++ для класса все таки делается отдельная структура "таблица виртуальных функций" и в экземпляре класса храниться только указатель на такую таблицу. Да, это конечно лишнее обращение к памяти, зато набор указателей на функции храниться только один раз для класса, а не для каждого экземпляра. А что касается вашего вопроса, то ответ тут может быть только один: "Такова жизнь, компиляторы не могут догадываться до всего на свете"

Comment: @Mike а вот это хорошее замечание, сейчас сделаю такую табличку. Благодарю :)

Comment: на godbolt'е MSVC-2015 кстати [нормально вызывает](https://godbolt.org/z/ZXsF8G) через rcx... @IlyaPakhmutov, ты случаем оптимизацию то не забыл включить?

Comment: по ходу забыл, как поставил релиз версию, так тоже стало через rcx вызывать, ну еп... даже апвоут поставить не могу, но походу ответ тут

Comment: У меня один вопрос: "Зачем?" У языка есть свои функции. Если нужны классы, то не лучше ли использовать ЯП в котором они есть??? Это как забивать гвоздь гаечным ключом... При желании можно, но молотком было бы удобнее...

Comment: @Ljil для понимания, я совершееенно не понимаю как работает половина языка С++, и я НЕ нашел учителя, даже в европе в институте, который бы знал как это работает. Все бы хорошо, но до реальных прогеров не достучаться, как я не пытался, меня просто игнорят. Поэтому я решил взять все в свои руки и сделать свой гвоздь с блекджеком и шлюхами. Если хочешь, объясни лично, я хочу учиться, просто учить никто не хочет, нормально, даже за деньги

Comment: @IlyaPakhmutov ну я тоже учусь) И логика которую я понял - нужно использовать подходящее средство. А про плюсы, так на мой взгяд 90% людей их не знает)) ибо раз в 3 года набрасывается всякой дичи, которая непонятно как работает)

Comment: @Ljil а я патологически ненавижу магию. Если присоединишься, образуем общество антимагов, которые сверхкруто могут использовать то что имеется ибо понимают как оно работает. Я уже понимаю как классы сделаны вплоть до асма.

Comment: @IlyaPakhmutov не забывай первое правило общества антимагов!